# Facebook graph api 2.5 rate limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) it is stated that "Rate limiting is calculated by taking the number of users your app had the previous day and adding today's new logins. This gives a base number of users that your app has.".

What is defined as "users"? Is it the number of user access tokens generated or the number of access tokens used for API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"users" are people who authorized your App. See docs:

> As an example, if your app had 10 users yesterday and 5 new logins today, that would give you a base of 15 users.

Meaning, 15 authorized people/users. Not sure why that definition is important for you, the most important thing is this one:

> Each each app is given an allotment of 200 API calls per user in any
>   given 60 minute window.

1 User = 1 User Access Token.

Comment: What's the difference between "users" and "logins"? Why do they say "users yesterday" and "logins today"?

Comment: i am not sure what´s there to explain, to be honest. "5 new logins" means "5 new users have authorized your app".

Comment: I mean why don't they say "total users currently", but instead split yesterday and today?

Comment: Because that would be a totally different value? Your app might have 1,000 users that have used it at some point before – but if only 10 of those logged in to your app yesterday, and you have 5 new logins (by users that weren’t using your app before), then the base number used for rate limit calculation is those 10 + 5 = 15.

Comment: @CBroe So if I create a new app, and one user logins and gets a 60 day access token, 2 days later the token cannot be used because the rate limit is 0?

Comment: No, that should not happen. Don’t try and look at such edge cases, that does not make much sense. API limiting is mainly for apps that make a lot of requests – and with those, how much of “a lot” is actually permitted, is calculated based on the users they have.